# Azure CLI ML Throws TypeError: __init__() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

Tags: python, azure, azure-cognitive-services, azure-machine-learning-service

I'm attempting to follow this [tutorial](https://github.com/microsoft/recommenders/blob/master/notebooks/05_operationalize/als_movie_o16n.ipynb) and am getting the following error. I'm working in jupyter notebook with python 3. I am trying to build a recommendation engine using Azure tools and the Microsoft doc I attached.

TypeError: **init**() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

[I have attached an image of code from jupyter notebook to demonstrate proper formatting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gnzza.png)

I've tried solutions to roll back my Azure Python SDK using Pip. I run pip install --upgrade azureml-sdk and all looks good. Thanks very much for any and all help!

The code appears below:

```py
    print(workspace_name)
    ws = Workspace.create(
        name=workspace_name,
        subscription_id=subscription_id,
        resource_group=resource_group, 
        location=location,
        exist_ok=True
    )

The full error appears below:
'''
   TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-11-25e04e55f419> in <module>
      5     resource_group=resource_group,
      6     location=location,
----> 7     exist_ok=True
      8 )

~\.conda\envs\reco_pyspark\lib\site-packages\azureml\core\workspace.py in create(name, auth, subscription_id, resource_group, location, create_resource_group, sku, friendly_name, storage_account, key_vault, app_insights, container_registry, cmk_keyvault, resource_cmk_uri, hbi_workspace, default_cpu_compute_target, default_gpu_compute_target, private_endpoint_config, private_endpoint_auto_approval, exist_ok, show_output)
    437 
    438         if location:
--> 439             available_locations = _available_workspace_locations(subscription_id, auth)
    440             available_locations = [x.lower().replace(' ', '') for x in available_locations]
    441             location = location.lower().replace(' ', '')

~\.conda\envs\reco_pyspark\lib\site-packages\azureml\core\workspace.py in _available_workspace_locations(subscription_id, auth)
   1556     if not auth:
   1557         auth = InteractiveLoginAuthentication()
-> 1558     return _commands.available_workspace_locations(auth, subscription_id)

~\.conda\envs\reco_pyspark\lib\site-packages\azureml\_project\_commands.py in available_workspace_locations(auth, subscription_id)
    334     :rtype: list[str]
    335     """
--> 336     response = auth._get_service_client(ResourceManagementClient, subscription_id).providers.get(
    337         "Microsoft.MachineLearningServices")
    338     for resource_type in response.resource_types:

~\.conda\envs\reco_pyspark\lib\site-packages\azureml\core\authentication.py in _get_service_client(self, client_class, subscription_id, subscription_bound, base_url)
    150         return _get_service_client_using_arm_token(self, client_class, subscription_id,
    151                                                    subscription_bound=subscription_bound,
--> 152                                                    base_url=base_url)
    153 
    154     def signed_session(self, session=None):

~\.conda\envs\reco_pyspark\lib\site-packages\azureml\core\authentication.py in _get_service_client_using_arm_token(auth, client_class, subscription_id, subscription_bound, base_url)
   1620     else:
   1621         # converting subscription_id, which is string, to string because of weird python 2.7 errors.
-> 1622         client = client_class(adal_auth_object, str(subscription_id), base_url=base_url)
   1623     return client
   1624 

TypeError: __init__() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
'''
```

Comment: Please do not post images of code. Instead post the code as text in a code block. See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: What environment are you using? Databricks? Also what SDK version is installed?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the `Workspace.from_config()` and the `config.json` method? Check out [this doc page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-configure-environment) on how the set up your environment.